# What is the probability of arriving at a traffic light when it is red if the red signal flashes for 30 seconds, the yellow

Tags: statistics

What is the probability of arriving at a traffic light when it is red if the red signal flashes for 30 seconds, the yellow signal for 5 seconds, and the green signal for 45 seconds

Let red be R , yellow  be Y and green be G

P(R and Y and G )= 30/60 *5/60 * 45/60 =1/32

is that correct ???

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calculating P(R and Y and G)? Why not just P(R)? Am I misreading the question? Because to me, the answer just seems to be $P(R)=\frac{30}{30+5+45}=\frac{30}{80}=\frac{3}{8}$

Comment: Or in some countries it is also yellow between red and green (not just between green and red) so the answer would then be 30/85 = 6/19

Comment: You are right, I had not thought of that!